# Попытка отсортировать массив

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
// Поддержка кириллицы в консоли Windows
system("chcp 1251 > nul");

// Создание вектора из строк
std::vector<std::string> students;

// Буфер для ввода фамилии студента
std::string buffer = "";

std::cout <<"\n\t "<<  "     Вводите фамилии студентов. "
          <<"\n\t"<< "По окончание ввода введите пустую строку"<<"\n "<< 
std::endl;

do {
    std::getline(std::cin, buffer);
    if (buffer.size() > 0) {
        // Добавление элемента в конец вектора
        students.push_back(buffer);
    }
} while (buffer != "");


// Сохраняем количество элементов вектора
int vector_size = students.size();     //unsigned   !@!!!!!!!!!    

std::cout <<"\n"<<std::endl;
// Вывод заполненного вектора на экран
std::cout<< "\t"<< "Ваш вектор." << std::endl;
for (int i = 0; i < vector_size; i++) {    //
    std::cout<<"\t"<<i+1<<". " << students[i] << std::endl;
}
std::cout <<"\n"<<std::endl;
std::sort(students.begin(), students.end());
for (int i = 0; i < vector_size; i++){
    std::cout <<"\t"<<i+1<<". "<< students[i] << std::endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Все поправил. Только с выводомa фамилий не пойму, как сделать, чтобы 
печаталось на крае с отступом `\t`.

Comment: Ну а чего Вы хотели? Используете строки с++ и хотите их просто скормить функциям си? почитайте, чего хотят strcpy() в аргументах. Да и зачем они у Вас, при живых `string`? Зачем используете си-строки совместно со `string`?

Comment: Когда не кому помочь, пытаюсь что то делать. Спасибо за просмотр и ответ.

Comment: Если нет никаких идеологических причин (типа как: так повелел Заратустра/преподаватель), замените `char str_spisok[29][19], str[19];` на строки с++, и тогда сможете совсем избавиться от `strcpy()` - вместо него вполне подойдет `=`.

Comment: И лучше создайте себе проект в CodeBlocks - он это умеет. Без проекта Вы не сможете нормально настраивать опции сборки (как минимум).

Comment: Проект в  в CodeBlocks я создал, в нем и работаю. А вот разбирась пока не очень, поэтому и сижу здесь. Иной раз и путаю Си и Си++.Запутался потому, что пытаюсь  методом тыка что то сделать. Знаний мало. Книжки читаю. Ошибаюсь. Как написано на сайте, если не хочешь быть дураком - спроси. Вот я и прошу помощи и понимания. С уважением к Вам, новичок.

Comment: Так собственно, и в чем же вопрос? Чтобы убрать ошибки компиляции - я написал. Создаете консольный проект (уже создали, ок - часть ругательств должна была уйти). Затем, замените строки си на string и на вектор из string (у Вас уже есть в коде такое). Замените strcpy() на нужные конструкции со строками с++ (присваивание, может еще выделение подстроки). Когда начнет компилировать без ошибок, можно будет переходить к проверке алгоритма (Вы какой именно метод сортировки хотели реализовать? - может, лучше начать с того, что попроще?)

Comment: Да, если Вы хотите сортировать что-то с русскими буквами... Еще нужно указать локаль ;-) . Но опять же, я бы предложил сначала сортировать целые числа, а уже потом перейти к строкам...

Comment: Про локаль можно по подробнее

Comment: Я попытаюсь, но комментарий для этого не предназначен. Вообще, локализация подразумевает набор национальных данных, типа: представление даты, валюта, десятичный разделитель. алфавит и т.п. Относительно сортировки важен порядок следования символов (алфавит, LC_COLLATE). Вы можете надеяться, что в используемой Вами кодировке буквы расположены в том же порядке, что и номера символов. Но это не так. В cp1251 буквы Ё идут перед всеми другими русскими. В кои8 - еще хуже. Задавая локаль (set_locale() или объект STL locale) Вы сможете использовать std::lexicographical_compare() для сортировки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Разбор полетов

#### Самый главный совет: Прислушивайтесь к компилятору

1. Неиспользуемые переменные

   ```
   temp.c:242:6: warning: unused variable 'str_spisok' [-Wunused-variable]
   char str_spisok[29][19], str[19];

   temp.c:240:18: warning: unused variable 'c' [-Wunused-variable]
   int i, a, b, c, n;
   ```

   **Что говорит компилятор?**

   *Предупреждение: неиспользуемая переменная `str_spisok`.*
   *Предупреждение: неиспользуемая переменная `c`.*

   **Что делаем мы?**

   Убираем переменные, они же не используются! Мелочь, но лог по-чище станет.
2. Опечатка

   ```
   temp.c:288:11: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\320'
   cout << "\Массив после сортировки: \n";
   ```

   **Что говорит компилятор?**

   *Предупреждение: неизвестная [escape-последовательность](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) `'\320'`.*

   **Что делаем мы?**

   Стираем обратный слэш: `"Массив после сортировки: \n"`.
3. Использование необъявленных сущностей

   ```
   temp.c:288:3: error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope
   cout << "\Массив после сортировки: \n";
   ^~~~

   temp.c:288:3: note: suggested alternative:
   In file included from temp.c:234:0:
   c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\iostream:61:18: note:   'std::cout'
   extern ostream cout;  /// Linked to standard output
                 ^~~~
   ```

   **Что говорит компилятор?**

   *Ошибка: `cout` не был объявлен в этом пространстве.*
   *Заметка: рекомендуемая альтернатива - `std::cout`.*

   **Что делаем мы?**

   Следуем предложению компилятора и заменяем `cout` на `std::cout`.
4. Сравнение между знаковой и беззнаковой переменной

   ```
   temp.c:272:19: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
   for (int i = 0; i < vector_size; i++) {
   ```

   **Что говорит компилятор?**

   *Предупреждение: сравнение между знаковым и беззнаковым целочисленным выражением.*

   **Что делаем мы?**

   Логичнее всего сделать переменную `i` беззнаковой переменной, т.к. индекс не может быть отрицательным (а `i` в этих целях и используется):

   ```
    for (unsigned i = 0; ...)
   ```
5. Присваивание с разными типами

   ```
   temp.c: In function 'int main()':
   temp.c:284:47: error: cannot convert '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >::value_type {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*' for argument '2' to 'char* strcpy(char*, const char*)'
                          strcpy(str,students[b-1]);
                                                  ^
   temp.c:285:55: error: cannot convert '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >::value_type {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' to 'char*' for argument '1' to 'char* strcpy(char*, const char*)'
                          strcpy(students[b-1],students[b]);
                                                          ^
   temp.c:286:45: error: cannot convert '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >::value_type {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' to 'char*' for argument '1' to 'char* strcpy(char*, const char*)'
                          strcpy(students[b],str);
   ```

   **Что говорит компилятор?**

   *Ошибка: не могу преобразовать тип `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>` к типу `char*` для первого аргумента функции `char* strcpy(char*, const char*)`.*

   **Что делаем мы?**

   Сначала *внимательно* смотрим на ошибку. Функция первым аргументом принимает `char*`, а мы ей подсовываем `string`.

   У нас всего два варианта решения этой проблемы: 1) сменить тип переменной на `char*`; 2) использовать другую функцию (или, вообще, другой подход).

   Мы воспользуемся вторым способом. Вместо

   ```
   strcpy(str,students[b-1]);                            
   strcpy(students[b-1],students[b]);                               
   strcpy(students[b],str);
   ```

   Напишем

   ```
    str = students[b-1];
    students[b-1] = students[b];
    students[b] = str;
   ```
6. Теперь у нас новая ошибка: Несовместимые типы в присваивании

   ```
   temp.c: In function 'int main()':
   temp.c:280:39: error: incompatible types in assignment of '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >::value_type {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' to 'char [19]'
                         str = students[b-1];
   ```

   **Что говорит компилятор?**

   *Ошибка: несовместимые типы в присваивании. Переменная типа `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>` присваивается переменной типа `char [19]`.*

   **Что делаем мы?**

   Меняем тип переменной `str` с `char[19]` на `std::string`:

   ```
   std::string str;
   ```

Теперь мы (наконец-то!) можем скомпилировать и запустить программу. Но она, естественно, не будет работать *правильно*.

### Как заставить ее работать верно?!

Заменить

```
 // Попытка отсортировать
    for (b=n;b>=a;b--){                                               
      ch1=students[b-1][0];  
      ch2=students[b][0];                                                     
           if (ch1>ch2){ 
                 strcpy(str,students[b-1]);                            
                 strcpy(students[b-1],students[b]);                               
                 strcpy(students[b],str);                                         
           }                                                                
     }
```

На

```
std::sort(students.begin(), students.end());
```

Не забудьте подключить заголовочный файл `<algorithm>`!

А `for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)` заменить на `for (i = 0; i < vector_size; i++)`.

Почему? Подумайте сами, основываясь на новых предупреждениях компилятора.

### Советы

1. **Определитесь с языком.** Не стоит смешивать C и C++. Кто-бы что ни говорил, но это разные языки.
2. **Форматируйте код.** Привыкайте к нормальному форматированию кода с начала обучения. Ну а добавлять плохо отформатированный код в вопрос — это моветон. Кому хочется разбираться в бесконечной простыне кода? Стоит прочитать про [coding-style](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82_%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0).
3. **Пространства имен.** Где-то вы пишете `std::cout`, где-то — просто `cout`. Лучше писать все в одном стиле. Подробнее о том, стоит ли использовать `using namespace` [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265039/using-std-namespace).
4. **Счетчики циклов.** Некоторые циклы вы записываете так:

   ```
   // Попытка отсортировать
   for (b = n; b >= a; b--) {
   ...
   for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
   ```

   Причем ни переменная `b`, ни `i` больше нигде не используются. Мы же не в C89, да? Лучше будет объявлять эти переменные прямо в заголовке цикла:

   ```
   // Кстати, почему b? Счетчики принято называть i, j, k... Правим!
   for (int i = n; i >= a; i--) {
   ...
   for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
   ```

   Почему лучше? Мы, по крайней мере, избавились от двух переменных, которые захламляют пространство имен внутри функции `main`. Кроме того, уменьшили "длительность жизни" (*"Совершенный код" Стив Макконнелл. Часть 3.10. Переменные. Область видимости*) переменных.
5. **Не используйте русский текст в коде во время обучения**. Это тот еще геморрой, который только отвлекает от обучения. Если не в ладах с английским, используйте транслит: `std::cout << "Vvedite chislo: "`. Уж лучше так...

### Второй самый главный совет: Не бойтесь задавать вопросы

Комментарий автора:

> Проект в в CodeBlocks я создал, в нем и работаю. А вот разбирась пока
>   не очень, поэтому и сижу здесь. Иной раз и путаю Си и Си++.Запутался
>   потому, что пытаюсь методом тыка что то сделать. Знаний мало. Книжки
>   читаю. Ошибаюсь. Как написано на сайте, если не хочешь быть дураком -
>   спроси. Вот я и прошу помощи и понимания. С уважением к Вам, новичок.
>   – igorekvp

Никто из нас не рождается кулц-хакерами и труЪ C++ программистами. Все мы учимся. Мне (да и всем) было также трудно, как вам. Не стесняйтесь, задавать вопросы, вам с удовольствием ответят!

Comment: Спасибо,разложили все по полочкам. for (int i = n; i >= a; i--)  уже разобрался, как я понял то простое объявление прямо в программе.Осваиваю дальше.

Comment: Все поправил.Только с выводом Фамилий не пойму, как сделать, чтобы 
    печаталось на крае с отступом  "\t"

Comment: И еще хотелось бы иметь пронумерованные списки

Comment: @igorekvp, это решается буквально парой символов.

Comment: Добавил вывод с нумерацией. А  как сделать, чтобы и в вводилось с нумерацией?

Comment: @igorekvp, `int k = 1; \ do { \ std::cout << k++ << ". "; \ ...`

Comment: Программа готова.Спасибо за помощь. Нужно,что-нибудь нажать или отметить?

Comment: @igorekvp, был рад помочь)